# Evaluation nets web-based editor: searching for the toolkit

Tags: java, web-applications, petri-net

My goal is to implement web based editor for evaluation nets (extension of Petri nets), something like [that swing app](http://pipe2.sourceforge.net/), language - Java. However I've never implemented rich web applications like that, so I am searching for the proper toolkit now. Currently I am thinking about GWT, but, as far as I have no expirience with it, I want to consider another options too. Hoping for your advice.

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of alternative options:

[Vaadin](http://vaadin.com/) is my favourite. you can build a web GUI without having to know javascript at all in the same manner you build a swing desktop application. Have a look at its [demo](http://vaadin.com/demo). vaadin comes with a professional look so it is easy to build something that look good.

Vaadin stores its backing GUI objects in session so if client idle for longer than the seestion timeout, they will have to refresh the application.

Another one similar to Vaadin is Apache [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/).