# Evaluation net editor

Tags: process, editor, workflow, agent-based-modeling, petri-net

I am looking for a editor for Evaluation nets (E-net, extension of Petri nets).

Something like:

- [PIPE2](https://pipe2.sourceforge.net/), or
- [WoPeD](http://woped.dhbw-karlsruhe.de/), or
- [Yasper](http://www.yasper.org/) (but it not open source and works on Windows only).

I only found [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015241/evaluation-nets-web-based-editor-searching-for-the-toolkit) and not found anything about the result of his works.

I am using evaluation net instead of petri net for modelling agent-based negotiation protocols because in this issue the diagrams are easier to read.